# Gitlab-CI for Multiple Repositories

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to gitlab-ci. So my question may or may not make sense.

I have 3 repositories, I want to set-up gitlab-ci for each of these.

The 3 projects are running on the same server.

I have installed a gitlab-runner on the server, and on gitlab-ui I have used the same runner that i Enabled for Repo 1 to be used for Repo 2 and 3.

My Pipeline works fine for Repo 1. But fails for 2 and 3.

here is the error
`ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: exit status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information`

Comment: Where is the error you provided coming from - is it output of the job execution or from gitlab runner logs? As would suggest to [run gitlab runner in debug mode](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/#run-in---debug-mode) and check the logs - maybe there will be some hints.

Comment: Thank you @IliaKondrashov, I will give it a try.